# Unable to call more than one onclick event for more than one button in android

Tags: android, button

I have small query in android.
I have one activity in which it has 3 buttons and on one button click I am displaying the AlertDialog box and on second button click I am displaying the List Dialog Box and On 3rd button click I am toggle the OnScreen Key board in android.

my problem is that I was able to call the first button and when I click the 2nd and 3rd button they are not responding and also I have checked by inserting breakpoints on respective click event functions, the control flow is not at all going inside the functions. simple it skips the fun and going to the end of the main OnCreate function.

here is the code I have used for the first 2 buttons...

```
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ShowListDialog();
        }
    });

    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowList);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ShowOneDialog();
        }
    });
```

I am calling the functions ShowOneDialog() and ShowListDialog() functions and hope that functions are not needed
and for the 3rd button click event is here below...

btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToggle);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputMethodManager inmgr=(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inmgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

You have set your btn as button1, and so you've only attached a listener to THAT button, which is why your other button isn't doing anything.

Comment: Yes I am doing that in second line as btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowList); can't we assign in this way I mean to a single object assign and re-assign so that a single object is enough for how many buttons we have.  can't we go in that way does this cause any problems in our code.

Answer (score 1):

Create an separate `OnClickListener` and add this Listener to all buttons as:

```
 Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
 Button btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowList);
 ....

 btn.setOnClickListener(buttonclickhandler);
 btn1.setOnClickListener(buttonclickhandler);
 ....

 View.OnClickListener buttonclickhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.button1:ShowListDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.btnShowList: ShowOneDialog();
            break;
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why can't we do assign to same btn object every time? why can't we use the same object all the time? Does we need to declare a separate object to every button we are using in our app?

Comment: @Ganesh : yes if you are using same instance of button for adding OnClickListener then it's not possible . in this case always last button click work so u will need to create all separate instead of buttons's and add OnClickListener to each

Comment: @Ganesh : if this answer help u in solving your current issue then mark it as answer for good accept rare

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ShowListDialog();
    }
});

Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowList);
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ShowOneDialog();
    }
});
```

Comment: Vikram Please do see my above comment on the code. Why can't we do in that manner. Please do see before comment.

Comment: @Ganesh: We cannot do in that manner because one object of button can be attached to only one view at a time. If you attach it to another view (button) ,the previous one will be lost and newly added button will only be remain functional as it was happening in your case. So if you want all buttons to be functional simultaneously you have to create separate button objects.